# How can I convert the values of a dictionary that are list of elements to a tuple of (tuples of coordinates)?

Tags: python-3.x

For example, I have this dict:

```
{'CUBE': ['0,0;0,1;1,0;1,1'], 
  'Z': ['0,0;1,0;1,1;2,1', '0,0;0,1;1,-1;1,0'], 
  'S': ['0,0;0,1;1,1;1,2', '0,0;1,-1;1,0;2,-1'],
  etc etc}
```

My goal is to convert this: ['0,0;0,1;1,0;1,1'], to this: ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))

Comment: In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  It is however, counter productive to dump all code.  Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set.  See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting `['0,0;0,1;1,0;1,1']` to `((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))` can be done as follows:

```py
>>> l = ['0,0;0,1;1,0;1,1']
>>> tuple(tuple(int(x2) for x2 in x1.split(',')) for x1 in l[0].split(';'))
((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))
```

This `split`s the `str` at `;` to get the pairs of values. It then `split`s each pair (still an `str`) at `,` to get the individual values of the pair, converts those values to `int`, and packs them together in a `tuple`. Finally, it packs all the `tuple`s to a `tuple`.

Now, applying the above to your `dict`:

```py
>>> d = {'CUBE': ['0,0;0,1;1,0;1,1'], 
...   'Z': ['0,0;1,0;1,1;2,1', '0,0;0,1;1,-1;1,0'], 
...   'S': ['0,0;0,1;1,1;1,2', '0,0;1,-1;1,0;2,-1']}
>>>
>>> for k, v in d.items():
...    for i, e in enumerate(v):
...        d[k][i] = tuple(tuple(int(x2) for x2 in x1.split(',')) for x1 in e.split(';'))
... 
>>> d
{'CUBE': [((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1))], 'Z': [((0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (2, 1)), ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, -1), (1, 0))], 'S': [((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (1, 2)), ((0, 0), (1, -1), (1, 0), (2, -1))]}
```

It should be clear what the outer loop does. The inner loop updates each `str` in the `list`s that are the `value`s of your `dict` to become the desired `tuple` of `tuple`s.